# How to PHP decode JSON from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

On **MySQL** I have this **JSON** value

```
{"length":1847,"data":[0,0,0,0,-46,37]}
```

On **PHP** I need to string in array the "data" objects, so I tried:

```
$json = $row['wave'];
$json_array = json_decode($json);
$json_wave = $json_array["data"];
```

It gives me `internal server error 500`, so I tried:

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

What I got is:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (5) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1847)
  ["data"]=>
  array(3694) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(0)
    [3]=>
    int(0)
    [4]=>
    int(-46)
    [5]=>
    int(37)
  }
}
```

I need to output this string `0,0,0,0,-46,37`, why is my code not working?

Comment: add second parameter TRUE into `$json_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);` to make it associative array then use `$json_wave = $json_array["data"];
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want decode JSON to array you shoud use json_decode function with additional parameter ($assoc as true):

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can look to documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

**json_decode()** by default returns an Object instead of an array. If you want to decode the **JSON String** in Array json_decode accepts second parameter as `boolean`.

If the second parameter is `true` **json_decode()** will return the value in forms of array.

So your code will look something like this,

```
$json = $row['wave'];
$json_array = json_decode($json,true);
$json_wave = $json_array["data"];
```

Second parameter's by default value is `false`.

To get the data from Object you can access it like this,

```
print_r($json_array->data);
```

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you want that last variable to be the string you need this

```
$json_array = json_decode($json);
$json_wave = implode(',', $json_array->data);
```

Because your JSON contains an object, PHP puts it into an object by default. That's what `var_dump` means when it says `stdClass`

Answer (score 0):

Your var_dump shows that the row is decoded as an object, so you cannot access its fields using array notation.

Change

```
$json_wave = $json_array["data"];
```

To

```
$json_wave = $json_array->data;
```

Alternatively, if you want to work with arrays rather than objects, you can set the 2nd parameter to json_decode as below:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're trying to treat object like an array. `json_decode` wihtout second parameter converts json_string to an object. use `json_decode($json, true)` to say 'hey, convert my json string to an array, not object'. On the other hand you can just use `$json_array->data` instead `$json_array["data"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$json = '{"length":1847,"data":[0,0,0,0,-46,37]}';
$a = json_decode($json);
print_r($a->data);
```

Value after `json_decode` in variable `$a` is stored in the object form and you can not get the object value like `$a['data']` so you have to use in this manner `$a->data`